# Firestore Rules: Allow Users only to write to their own document and fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How to Allow Users only to write to their own document and fields in firestore?

---

**NOTICE!**
 
I have changed uid to email instead.

---

This is rules I have tried but not working:

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/request.auth.token.email {
         allow write: if get(path("databases/" + database + "/documents/users/" + request.auth.token.email)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: SEE IMAGE FOR DATABASE HERE]

Comment: I strongly recommend against using email instead of UID. Email addresses can change, but the UID of a user will never change.  UID is a far better choice for document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS WORKED!** =)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{email} {
       allow update, delete: if request.auth.token['email'] == email;
       allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTICE!** This rules will **NOT** work in test with the *FIREBASE SIMULATOR*, But it will work for real on my website.